# SSH works fine at start but permission denied (publickey) after some time

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, multiple-instances

I have 3 instances on GCP all ubuntu. I try to ssh from the private IPs in each as soon as I start the machines and they work fine but after some time they start throwing errors.

```
shiv1499@ansiblemaster:~$ ssh 10.128.0.5
Last login: Tue Sep 17 15:42:19 2019 from 10.128.0.3
shiv1499@target2:~$

shiv1499@ansiblemaster:~$ ssh 10.128.0.4
Last login: Tue Sep 17 15:42:09 2019 from 10.128.0.3
shiv1499@target1:~$

shiv1499@ansiblemaster:~$ ssh 10.128.0.4
shiv1499@10.128.0.4: Permission denied (publickey).

shiv1499@ansiblemaster:~$ ssh 10.128.0.5
shiv1499@10.128.0.5: Permission denied (publickey)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually is caused by the ssh-agent.

When it happen, try the following:

```sh
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add YOUR_KEYS_PATH # maybe not necessary
```

The brute solution, is force the ssh connection to use the certificate:

```sh
ssh -i your_priv_key user@ip
```